Vue CLI not re-rendering
I am working on a project using Flask and Vue, and I am having trouble with the front end. I am using Vue Cli with Babel and router packages.
Now I am trying to make a Vue view file.

I start my server.

make changes (e.g. changing some text, style, etc.)

I am not able to see the changes without stopping the server and starting again manually. On average, it takes 5 to 20 minutes.


Is there a way for the Vue server to automatically update itself, as I code?
I am new to Vue, and this is for a college project. I am told that the server detects changes automatically and updates them, but that is not happening in my case.
I am sharing my config files here.
App.vue:
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<style scoped>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>

main.js:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')

babel.config.js:
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}

jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  }
}

pacakge.json:
`{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
`

vue.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})


I have created 3+ Vue projects, but the result is the same, I am not sure what other dependencies to install.

This may be for several reasons, firstly you do not update the browser cache when the page is reloaded, this is a common situation that leads to these kind of problems, the solution is to disable caching, and second, you need to make sure that the server is running in npm development mode run serve (or yarn serve if using Yarn), or you can create a project again to check if this hot reload works.
Good Luck!
